# Java printf not working as expected when dividing

Tags: java, printf, double

Consider the following code:

- value of `houses` variable is 24
- value of `underContract` variable is 19

```java
private static void architecht(int houses, int underContract) {
    System.out.printf("\nOccupancy Rate: %,.2d ", houses/underContract);
```

Exception is given: `java.util.IllegalFormatPrecisionException`

Comment: That dot shouldn't be in an integral format specifier

Comment: You are using the `d` format for integers - you can't specify `.2` for that. Maybe you wanted to use `f` for  floating point - you would also need to use floating point division rather than the integer division you are currently using.

Comment: Note that dividing two integers in java always results in an integer...

Comment: Which output had you expected or wanted?